# Is "Just a friendly advice" grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality, uncountable-nouns

I know that "advice" is uncountable and thus is incompatible with the article "a".

However, the phrase "Just a friendly advice" seems to be rather widespread.

Is it idiomatic, or incorrect? What is a more grammatical form?

Comment: Advice is not countable, period. It is not like beer. Whereas "a brewery produces beer" and you can have "three beers", someone is a "source of advice" and he cannot give you "three advices". Google is not valid because not all English web pages are written by people competent in English. Also, web scrapers multiply web search results. Google's estimated number of pages doesn't mean anything. It will say that two million pages contain matches, but when you go through the list exhaustively, it's just a few pages of hits (even if you repeat the search with the omitted pages included).

Comment: @Kaz There is a [countable *advice*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/advice?s=t), which refers specifically to a type of official notification. But this is an uncommon use of the word and these are not ever friendly anyhow.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

If you use an article with *advice* you have to use a counter:

> A friendly *piece of* advice.
>
> A friendly *bit of* advice.

No one who is fluent in English (AmE or BrE) would say

> A friendly advice. [Wrong!]

To omit the article, those speakers would say

> Some friendly advice.

Answer (score 64):

Dear reader: I'm going to offer you a little friendly advice. When checking to see if something is "grammatical," do not rely on a Google search. Google will return hits from blogs and message boards, which are not necessarily reliable sources for determining correct English. Google will also return other odd nuggets, such as [a fraction of a user's handle](http://answers.yahoo.com/activity?show=NYwPOsDaaa). Instead, use [**Google books**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22just%20a%20friendly%20advice%22&hl=en&safe=off&tbo=d&biw=1430&bih=788&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ei=BJIXUZC6ENOHqwG6kYAo&ved=0CAwQ_AUoAA), which restricts the search to published works, where the number of results will be a more reliable indicator.

For example, typing "just a friendly advice" into Google returns roughly 1,000,000 hits! Surely one million hits can't be wrong, right?  Well, let's look at a few of these (the text I have bolded may help indicate the reliability of the wording):

> <sub>From a [message board](http://www.nachi.org/bbsystem/viewtopic.php?t=10086&PHPSESSID=68ded59e609759dc8b34a0034a55af1e):</sub>
>   **Just a friendly advice!**
>   *So, here’s an advice.. Quitting is hard, but don't give up! **The easily stop smoking worldwide program** , Nosmoq was proven to be the easiest, most effective and possible real herbal treatment of smoking for just 4 to 7 days*
>
> <sub>From a [message board](http://forums.dpreview.com/forums/post/31867721):</sub>
>   **Re: WHOA! - Just a friendly advice**
>   *IMHO, I think is more self-explanatory to show crops at 1:1 ratio. **An square** helps to make a difference between the original and the crop at first sight.*
>
> <sub>From a [**cat**](http://cheezburger.com/4443793920):</sub>
>   *Just a friendly advice: think **veeery** carefully about what you're going to do next.*
>
> <sub>From a [message board](http://www.r6-forum.com/forums/showthread.php?t=162872):</sub>
>    **Just a friendly advice for those faulting their R6**
>   *So back when I first started riding with an 88FZ750 it always died on me. **So much that I always had jumper cables and a set of tools on me**. Now with my R6 I don't need the cables but I still carry a set of tools in case something does happen. Today was that day. On my way to work my **bazaar** unit crapped out and died leaving me with error 39 on the Side of the road. It was early morning so tech support were still sleeping. I didn't want to pay towing fees so I proceeded to remove the whole bazaar harness on the road, or just enough to get to work and home. After about 30 min I rewired the lower injectors back to stock and she fired right up! Not runnin perfect but she still gets to places. It was also 90 out at 8am so having water helps*.

As for that last one, I'd love to have that guy stop to help me on the side of the road, but I wouldn't want him proofreading my term paper.

Moving the search to Google books cuts the number of results down from roughly a million to a [very small handful](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22just%20a%20friendly%20advice%22&hl=en&safe=off&tbo=d&biw=1430&bih=788&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ei=BJIXUZC6ENOHqwG6kYAo&ved=0CAwQ_AUoAA#q=%22just%20a%20friendly%20advice%22&hl=en&safe=off&tbo=d&tbm=bks&ei=z5gXUaaoIujD2QWGqYH4AQ&start=10&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.42080656,d.aWM&fp=580004139bef3eaf&biw=1430&bih=761).

Some may claim there is "nothing wrong" with it; I suppose that would depend on what was meant by "wrong." If I can say, *"Just a friendly hint"*, shouldn't I also be able to say, *"Just a friendly advice"*? I suppose I *could* (after all, [this writer did](http://books.google.com/books?id=_3beZL6aUioC&pg=PA522&dq=%22just%20a%20friendly%20advice%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=dZkXUZ_xCKjw2QWY_oCACg&ved=0CD4Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22just%20a%20friendly%20advice%22&f=false)); however – discussion board titles notwithstanding – I think most hearers would find it awkward. I'd be more inclined to follow Robusto's guidance, which sounds much more natural to my ear.

Answer (score 31):

On the topic of *a friendly advice* having 1,070,000 hits - *some friendly advice* gets 137,000,000 hits. In other words, the 1,070,000 million, despite the impresive number of digits, is a fraction of 1% of the total and therefore 1,070,000 mistakes.

[Ngram confirms this.](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=some+friendly+advice%2Ca+friendly+advice&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)

*Advice* is uncountable, so it should be be "some friendly advice", which is reflected in the Ngram above.

Answer (score 14):

> Is "Just a friendly advice" grammatical?

Assuming you meant "grammatical" in its "grammatically correct" form, then... no. It isn't.

Advice is a non-countable noun and, as such, "an advice" is invalid. Injecting the adjective "friendly" does not change that.

Here are some correct equivalents:

- Just a friendly piece of advice.
- Just a friendly bit of advice.
- Just a friendly morsel of advice.
- Just some friendly advice.

The mistake you made, I think, was in trusting a Google hit count to suggest the correctness of an English phrase; a cursory glance across a few arbitrary websites indicates that this is silly.

Answer (score 6):

*Just a friendly advice* cannot be said to be **ungrammatical** as *advice* is sanctioned as being at least pluralisable on occasion by both the AHD and Collins, and definitely count on occasion (sense 3) by Webster's.

It falls quite close, however, to *Colourless green ideas sleep furiously* - not breaking rules of grammar (unless context forces the usual non-count meaning of *advice* to be inferred) (which 'friendly' strictly doesn't) - but *semantically* unacceptable / needing freewheeling looseness in usage.

Answer (score 1):

The Oxford English Dictionary lists *advice* as a count noun:

> 2b. As a count noun. -  (a) A piece of advice (sense 2a). Now chiefly Caribbean and S. Asian.

It lists usage back to the 13th century:

> 1418   in R. W. Chambers & M. Daunt Bk. London Eng. (1931) 195 (MED),   The same Ordynaunce turnyd in-to englysche be the Avyces of the Fraternite.

Grammatically, if a countable *advice* is just a bit of uncountable advice, it makes perfect sense. However, as the OED indicates, this usage is no longer current in all dialects of English, and thus will seem odd, unidiomatic, or ungrammatical.