# Term for something that can be advice but is actually a warning?

Tags: phrases, expressions

Is there a term to describe a phrase that can sound like advice but is actually a warning?

I work with math and algorithms and I often tell clients, "you will improve what you measure". I intend it to be a warning - measure the wrong thing and you are sunk. But it otherwise sounds like pretty good advice!

So is there something I can use to describe this type of phrase?

Comment: precautionary advice?

Answer (score 1):

***a word to the wise***, from [The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/word+to+the+wise)

> word to the wise (is enough).  and A word to the wise is sufficient.
>   Prov. You only have to hint something to wise people in order to get
>   them to understand it.; Wise people do not need long explanations.
>   (Often used to signal that you are hinting something.) John's a
>   pleasant man, but I wouldn't trust him with money. A word to the wise,
>   eh? Donna hinted about Lisa's drinking problem to Lisa's fiancé,
>   hoping that a word to the wise would be enough.

A bit of *friendly advice*: *Word to the wise* is informal and old-fashioned; moreover, the OP's clients may not be wise enough to understand what he is trying to impart.

***friendly advice*** is another possibility.  See the answer by @J.R. at the beginning of his answer to this ELU question: [Is "Just a friendly advice" grammatical?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103619/is-just-a-friendly-advice-grammatical/103627)

> Dear reader: I'm going to offer you a little friendly advice. When
>   checking to see if something is "grammatical," do not rely on a Google
>   search.

As J.R. used it, *friendly advice* was a bit snarky.  But the OP seems to be talking about face-to face communication, in which case, if his tone and attitude are right, the phrase will be understood as he wants it to be -- a helpful warning.

Answer (score 0):

There are many words for constructions like this in general (adage, proverb, saw) but I think the one that fits best here is *maxim*.

Answer (score 0):

### Easing into the topic

In the framework of [pragma-dialectis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma-dialectics#Rules_for_a_critical_discussion), an argumentation theory used to analyze and evaluate argumentative discourse in actual practice, the term to describe a phrase which can sound like advise but is actually a warning is described as ***argumentum ad baculum***, also known as ***'appeal to the stick.'***

In its fallacious form,

> the ***ad baculum*** derives its strength from an appeal to human timidity or fear and is a fallacy when the appeal is not logically related to the claim being made. In other words, the emotion resulting from a threat rather than a pertinent reason is used to cause agreement with the purported conclusion of the argument.

An couple of explicit examples would be:

- Chairman of the Board: 'All those opposed to my arguments for the opening of a new department, signify by saying, "I resign."'
- Chief editor to intern: 'You could publish that article, but don't forget who's paying your wage.'

See [this](http://philosophy.lander.edu/logic/force.html) info-packed reference for a more detailed description of the concept.

### Getting to the good stuff

The non-fallacious variant of the ***'appeal to the stick'*** manifests itself, also according to the above mentioned source,

> when the threat or the force is directly or causally related to the conclusion.

In our current context, as the OP has elaborated, **'you will improve what you measure'** is intended as an implicit warning, albeit having the appearance of a mere good-natured advice, which translates into the explicit **'measure the wrong thing and you are sunk'**, or better yet **'unless you measure the correct thing, you will not improve.'**

### Less formal alternatives

Although the above breakdown should help in answering the question of how to label occurrences of **'something that can be advice but is actually a warning'** for the OP's personal peace of mind, it would be rather tedious to attempt and relay such verbose definitions to clients.

In that regard, issuing out a simple, genuine ***friendly reminder*** for them to **'measure the right stuff'**, should suffice. :)