# In English, adjectives do not take a plural form. How do we explain the use of the adjective "sales" (as in sales growth, or sales decline)?

Tags: adjectives, grammatical-number

In English, adjectives do not take a plural form. How do we explain the use of  the adjective "sales" (as in sales growth, or sales decline)?

Comment: "Sales", in this sense, is a "collective" noun that has been "adjectivefied".

Comment: "Sales" is not an adjective there, though it functions as one. It's what's called an "attributive noun" or "noun adjunct."

Comment: _Donkey_ sanctuary; _dogs_ home. **Attributive nouns**. Usually singular in form, but obviously not always. There are arguably even new word-forms: working _mens_ club, _childrens_ clothing department. And old favourites: _credit_ card, _systems_ analyst.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is this noun used as an adjective?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87609/is-this-noun-used-as-an-adjective) ['points' in 'points victory']

Answer (score 1):

According to [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/sale), *sale* is not an adjective.

You are confusing a category of words *adjectives* with a function in noun phrase structure *modifier*. Modifiers in NPs can come from a variety of different categories. A selection from CaGEL p444:

i a. another **three** days b. the **barely forty** students present [Determiner Phrase]

ii a. his **wry** attitude b. many **very angry** farmers [Adjective Phrase]

iii a. the **defeated** army b. her **recently published** article [Verb Phrase]

iv a. the **gleaming** showroom b. three **steadily melting** marshmallows [Verb Phrase]

v a. its **entertainment** value b. those **Egyptian cotton** shirts [nominal]

vi a. a **dogs’** home b. a **young children’s** edition [nominal]

*Sales*, as it is used in *sales growth*, is a mass noun (Lexico):

> 1 *[mass noun]* The exchange of a commodity for money; the action of
>   selling something.
>
> ‘we withdrew it from sale’
>
> 1.1 (**sales**) A quantity or amount sold.
>
> ‘price cuts failed to boost sales’
>
> 1.2 (**sales**) The activity or business of selling products.
>
> ‘director of sales and marketing’

Answer (score 0):

**Sales** is a plural noun.

[Noun1][noun2] = the [noun2] associated with [noun1]

The *Language Department* = the *department* associated with *language*.

A *beer bottle* = a *bottle* associated with *beer*.

There can be several nouns together:

A *beer bottle shape* = a *shape* associated with a *bottle* that is itself associated with *beer*.

**Thus "sales growth" = the *growth* associated with *sales*.**

The nature of the association is given by the context.

Answer (score -1):

Although people often use the words "never" and "always" to describe rules about the English language reality is often more of "not usually" or "usually."

Imagine a wooden barrel full of apples, where each apple has either a red or green skin. Someone named "Irene" might say, "all of the apples in the barrel are red." Well, if you find a green apple, IRenestatement suddenly is put to the test. A truer statement is, "more than 90% of the apples in the barrel are red."

I encourage to translate any of the following statements...
 - "In English, we ***never*** [...]"
 - "In English, we ***always*** [...]"
 - "English has no [`X`s]"

... into...

- "More than 90% of the time, [...]"
- "More than 90% of the time, [...]"
- "English has almost no [`X`s] "

You might view the rule "In English, adjectives never take on a plural form," more like "adjectives usually aren't plural."

In the case of "***sales growth***" or "***sales decline***" the word "***sales***" is an adjective.

For example,

> "Johann studies ***tree*** growth"
>   More than 90% of the time ***tree*** is usually a noun, but in this case, ***tree*** is an adjective.
>
> Hannah studies ***baseball*** statistics

***baseball*** is usually used as a noun. But, in this example, ***baseball*** is being used as an adjective.

- Ian specializes in ***home*** design. (What kind of design? ***home*** design)
- Jacob likes ***flower*** arranging. (What kind of arranging? ***flower*** arranging)

> Aaron works as a ***dog*** trainer

In the example, "***dog***" is being used as an adjective acting on the word "***trainer***"
However, ***dog*** is usually a noun.

Pretty much any noun in English can be turned into an adjective.

Usually, a flat-bladed screwdriver is used put loosen or tighten single-slotted screws. However, flat-bladed screwdriver can also be used as a small pry bar. Words are tools, like screw-drivers. The word "Sales" is a tool.

The words "Sales" is sometimes used as an uncountable noun.

[image: chart for countable and uncountable nouns]

Notice that is it is awkward (not incorrect, but rare) to write things like:

- two golds, three golds, four golds
- one water, two waters, three waters

"***Sales***" is sometimes used as a countable noun...
 - 1 sale
 - 2 sales
 - 3 sales, 4 sales...

Other times, "***Sales***" is used as an uncountable noun:

- ***sales*** are up
- ***sales*** are down
- we need to increase ***sales***

In the phrase, "**sales growth**," the word "**sales**" is an adjectivized uncountable noun.

Comment: It's not "rare" to pluralize *water*. Every time you go into a restaurant and some in your party ask for water, the wait staffer asks "OK, that's three waters?" It is quite commonplace for individual portions of mass nouns to be referred to in the plural.

Comment: @Robusto You did not like my claim that it is "rare" to use the word "water" as a countable noun. How about we replace the word "rare" with the word "informal"? I claim that it is very ***informal*** to say, "I need three waters." The formal way to discretize a mass noun is to write "[countable noun] of [mass noun]." It is more formal to say, "three glasses of water," instead of "three waters." Also, it is more formal to write "seven bars of gold" instead of "seven golds." As one last example, it is  formal to say "two loaves of bread" and informal to say "two breads."

Comment: I'm very familiar with the use of counters with mass nouns. See [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103619/is-just-a-friendly-advice-grammatical), in which using a mass noun without a counter is just plain wrong. The point is, sometimes it's not wrong. Register shifts happen all the time. You could be at a formal dinner and still ask for three waters.