# What do Americans think of using 'cheers' to sign off an email?

Tags: american-english, british-english, email, valediction

I've suspected before that "Cheers" as an email sign-off is a bit of an English (or possibly Commonwealth) thing, but being English it's natural to me and I use it as the mood takes me to end an email.

When I email an American, what sort of impression does it give?  Are there any other English speaking cultures out there where it's a bit unfamiliar?

Comment: It just means *thanks* in the English sense.  Does that come across to people from elsewhere?

Comment: @Orbling - Thanks for clearing that up. As an American, I had no idea what the ubiquitous use of "cheers" by British English speakers was supposed to mean. Now it makes sense.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/332/how-to-end-an-email

Comment: It's also fairly common in Australia.

Comment: The question is quiet different, as it asks if American people would understand the use of _cheers_ as salutation in an email.

Comment: @Orbling, I disagree. I see it used to end e-mails without any gratitude being intended - merely something more friendly than a bare name, and less formal than other sign-offs.

Comment: @Peter Taylor: I was stating the meaning of the word in English, which is where the usage in emails is derived from.  When used in an email, it should hold this value.  But like most valedictions, is used without thought to meaning regularly.

Comment: @ssakl: It is used to say thank you, but also used primarily as the phrase to use when raising a glass to someone, for a toast.

Comment: @Orbling, the point I was trying to make was that you were stating your *belief* of its meaning in English, but that my observations didn't concord. kiamlaluno's reference to a dictionary which lists "good wishes on parting" as a possible meaning seems to fit my observations of its usage.

Comment: @Peter Taylor: You will note that in kiamlaluno's dictionary quotation, the usage I am referring to is also listed (3) as "chiefly British".  I am familiar with usages (1) & (3), usage (2) seems to be a combination of the other two.

Comment: Americans love it. They think it's a quaint English thing. They don't fully understand it, but that doesn't matter. They won't think it rude.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To me, as an American, it doesn't really get interpreted other than to flag to me that the writer is speaking British English. I have no idea when it is or is not proper to use "cheers" in British English, so it sort of gets ignored as to whether this is a formal or informal way of signing off.

Internationally, it's probably best to stick to a more formal "Thank you" or "I look forward to your reply" if the communication is with someone with whom you do not have a pre-established relationship. This is more important when the recipient is not a native speaker of English and may be confused.

Comment: Odd, I've seen it used so much (and use it myself) as an informal end to an email that I no longer see it as particularly British. To me it's perfectly understandable as it is used in a toast: "cheers!" *clink*. Mind you, I'm Canadian. Maybe it's even more British to american sensibilities.

Comment: Keep in mind that in America, 'Cheers!' is often said as an informal toast just before tipping back an alcoholic beverage.

Comment: @ghoppe the association with a toast is not relevant when ending an email. It simply means "thanks".

Comment: I assure you, to most English speaker's from the US who have not spent a lot of time in the UK or with British English speakers, it very succinctly distinguishes the person using it as a user of British English.

Answer (score 10):

As an American English native speaker, I interpret it as *"Thanks/Have a great day from someone from England (or possibly Australia)"*.  Not that they were intending the "from England" part - that is just my interpretation.

**Edit:** 
I do find myself using it sometimes lately :)  Also 'no worries', but I have some Australian friends, so I probably picked it up from them.

Answer (score 7):

As reported from the NOAD (*New Oxford American Dictionary*) the definition of *cheers* is the following:

> cheers /tʃɪ(ə)rz/
>   exclamation informal
>   expressing good wishes, in particular
>   • good wishes before drinking: *“Cheers,” she said, raising her glass*.
>   • [British] good wishes on parting or ending a conversation: *Cheers, Jack, see you later*.
>   • [chiefly British] gratitude or acknowledgment for something: *Billy tossed him the key. “Cheers, pal.”*

*Cheers* is therefore used to express good wishes in both American English and British English; it's probably understood to have that meaning in a specific context (e.g., before drinking).
I would use *good wishes*.

Comment: All true, and I can look it up in a dictionary too, but I know what it means.  I wanted to know how it made people *feel* in certain contexts, and how wide its usage is outside the UK.

Comment: I'm sorry, but really, *no* English-speaker in the US, the UK, Canada, India, South Africa, or anywhere else in the English-speaking world would say *good wishes* before a toast or as a parting greeting :) Cheers, mate!

Comment: Imagine an American, familiar with the first meaning cited, but not with the other two (British) meanings.  If he receives an email with "Cheers" at the end, he may imagine that the British guy sending it was imbibing an alcoholic beverage while writing... and that may not be the impression this British guy wants to convey.

Comment: I have exactly one friend who ends every e-mail with "Cheers".  He isn't British, but he likes to drink, so I always imagine him raising a glass with every e-mail.

Comment: Being a bit of an Anglophile, I love the _Cheers_ closing, and take it in the _good wishes on parting or ending a conversation_ sense, unless the _Thanks_ sense seems primarily or additionally intended. When my sister (a native American English speaker, like me) uses it, often, as an email sign-off, I know that she means it similarly (minus the _Thanks_ sense) by the context and sibling familiarity, as well as due to the fact that she often closes a handwritten card or note with _Cheers_ illustrated with a doodle of two clinking martini/champagne glasses.

Answer (score 7):

I am an American English native speaker, but I've been exposed to the British usage so much that I've ended a couple of emails with it myself. It always seemed like a fairly reasonable signoff.

Answer (score 1):

As a native American speaker, when I see British folk sign off "Cheers," I have always interpreted it as they are sending out a general well wishing. It does remind me of when Americans say "Cheers" when they click glasses in general goodwill to each other.

But more than that, whenever I hear a European say or write Cheers, I always think it sounds so cool and makes them seem so laid back, friendly, and even hip. I really love the phrase and always feel impressed when I hear it.  I'm not sure why.

In fact, I wish I could say it without feeling funny. But it feels like cultural appropriation to say it. But I totally support other Americans saying it if they want to. It's just not a trend in our culture yet so it sounds a little funny for us to be saying it.

Comment: "I wish I could say it without feeling funny. But it feels like cultural appropriation to say it."

It's kind of sad that we're at a place in our society where we feel like it's inappropriate or that we feel uncomfortable to use British English words as Americans. We aren't taking anything away from people when we "appropriate" parts of their language into ours. 

Almost every language has appropriated words from other languages for thousands of years. Just do it.