# Do Americans say 'cheers' to mean 'thanks'?

Tags: american-english, british-english

I find myself these days saying 'cheers' all the time as a kind of mild form of 'thanks', and I heard it said a lot round here (Northamptonshire, England).  It's not even a commoner thing, I'd say the middle class are likely to use it a lot.  Is it used this way in the US, or would you always consider 'cheers' as something to say when toasting?

Comment: Here are two questions that seem to be asking something slightly different, but the answers to them actually answer your question as well: [“Cheers” vs. “Thanks” in England](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1628/) and [Using 'cheers' to sign off an email?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10812/).

Comment: and you might need to translate 'commoner' for the non-Brit readers :) (though I may be wrong...)

Comment: @Benjol: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/commoner - doesn't say anything about definition 1 being British.  :-)

Comment: @Benjol: We Americans know what *commoner* means; it means "more common", of course! :)

Comment: I only picked it up because of Brits and Ozzie (and Kiwi) friends using it! Otherwise, had never heard of it before.

Comment: Some (pretentious) Americans use "cheers" now in the way they used "ciao" 15 years ago. To my ear, it never fails to sound forced.

Comment: I picked it up when I went to study in the UK and have been using it ever since. It did raise a few eyebrows with my American folks but they got used to it quickly enough.

Comment: “It's not even a commoner thing, I'd say the middle class are likely to use it a lot.” — we like to adopt some of your quaint phrases to make you feel better about your station in life.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: Ah, but will Americans have encountered 'working class'?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, Americans only use it as a toast, although we're aware that people from the UK and Australia use it as thanks or goodbye.

Comment: Some people use "Cheers" as thanks or goodbye but it is very rare.

Comment: @WalterJ89: and at least in some cases, it is a deliberately affected Britishism.

Comment: I've heard it used as a parting word here in the states. Dunno if it was just from transplanted Brits though (I know a few). Never noticed.

Comment: I've heard it used as "goodbye", but not "thanks" (until I started watching *Misfits*). Recently, my husband asked me about an email from a colleague that ended in "cheers". He was actually offended by it for some reason. I asked if the sender was from the UK, he said yes, and I explained it was "normal". So many may not be aware, as your answer states. (We are in NYC, by the way — not some backwater.)

Comment: @user24205: I disagree that it would be typical for an English/British person to use the word to sign off an email. It definitely carries a sense of 'thanks' rather than 'farewell' in the UK. (Even though it's a common way to end a phone conversation, that seems to convey 'thanks for speaking with me'.)

Comment: Signing off with "cheers" is pretty common in my experience (I'm English). It's my standard sign-off in emails to friends, and that of many people that I know. I can also confirm that it's also commonly used to mean "thanks" here where, again, it's very informal.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes it is used now to mean "thanks" or "you're welcome" in addition to the toasting context. I live in America and it is catching on, most likely because of the Internet and how interconnected the world has become these days with travel and mobile phones, etc. For better or worse, sayings and distinctions that used to be regional or worldly locators for where a person was from or grew up is not necessarily the case anymore. YouTube, TV shows, movies, friends, travel, and the Internet, etc., can teach anyone anything these days.

Comment: Yes, this is right. I mostly use it in writing.

Answer (score 0):

Some Americans will use "cheerio" to mean thanks or goodbye. But they are mainly "Anglo" Americans, or at least Americans who have spent some time in England.

Comment: Interesting. I'm not aware of "cheerio" ever being used to mean "thanks" in the UK.

Comment: As @Rupe pointed out, "cheerio" is most commonly used for goodbye in the UK and I've never heard it used as a replacement for "thanks".

Comment: @Frankie: I said ANGLO- Americans sometimes do this, not UK residents.

Comment: @TomAu thks pointing it out. I've misread it and obvious have no idea what Anglo-Americans say.

Comment: @TomAu I don't think either Frankie or I intended any criticism. But you did say "..who have spent some time in England", from which people could easily infer that the UK was to some degree a source of this usage, and so a clarification was in order. And like I said, it's *interesting* that Anglo-Americans might use it to mean "thanks".