# What is the preferred way to end an email?

Tags: email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are some expressions that can be used to end an email?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/332/what-are-some-expressions-that-can-be-used-to-end-an-email)

What is the best way to sign off in an email? I'm using 'Best Regards'. Is it right to use this, or should I use one of these alternatives:

1. Regards,
2. Warm Regards,
3. Thanks & Regards,