# end of the e-mail "warm wishes"

Tags: email, letter-writing

I have received an e-mail form a recruiter regarding a conference.

> Warm wishes, 
>   Jane Doe, Recruiter

Isn't it too personal for an e-mail with business connotation?

Comment: This is more a question of etiquette than English.

Comment: duplicate of: [What are some expressions that can be used to end an email?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/332/what-are-some-expressions-that-can-be-used-to-end-an-email)

Comment: I think this is more a question about connotation of an English idiom rather than etiquette :)

Comment: I think this is valid. It is about whether this English expression in this context is appropriate, which seems to match many other questions on here.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the nature of the business relationship. If you know the person yourself, and have dealt with and worked with them, then there is an element of a personal business relationship, in which cases, I would consider it acceptable. It is a friendly, but not intimate closing.

If it is an impersonal relationship - they are after your organisation, or it is a cold sales contact - then it is probably trying too hard, and it is inappropriate, I think. Or it is trying to be personal, when it isn't.

But emails are a very difficult area to judge correctly, as a new form of communications that do not lend themselves to the formality of letters, but are not always as intimate as they sometimes seem. I have had "warm wishes" from recruiters when I have spoken to them and worked with them for a while. I do not have a problem with it in this sort of context.