# Common ending lines for formal emails?

Tags: email, greetings, valediction

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are some expressions that can be used to end an email?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/332/what-are-some-expressions-that-can-be-used-to-end-an-email)

I know a few,

> Best regards
>   Best
>   Sincerely
>   Eagerly

Think of it as an email for first impression for a potential client. Formal but flexible.

Comment: This looks like a Not Constructive "list" question to me, with no possibility of a "right" answer. But I would suggest OP steers well clear of *Eagerly*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When concerned about propriety, treat an email as you would a classic business letter. (I'm assuming a US English speaking recipient).

"Yours faithfully" if you don't know their name.

"Yours sincerely" if you do.

[Here](http://esl.about.com/cs/onthejobenglish/a/a_basbletter.htm) is a decent guide to business letter writing, and the same rules apply to both email and traditional mail.