# Difference in tone between Regards, Best regards, Kind regards and Sincerely in emails

Tags: meaning, email, valediction, tone

I often end my emails just with "Regards, FirstName".

But I also often see "Best regards", "Kind regards" and "Sincerely".

What is the difference in tone and meaning? Is one more formal than the other? Is there a difference between US and UK?

Comment: @phenry The answers there seem to be mostly just lists of closings, not detailed explanations of when different ones are appropriate.

Comment: To be honest, people don't pay much mind to what these closings actually say. There are a few stock phrases that get used (some a bit more businesslike than others), but I've never spent much time wondering why someone ended with "Sincerely" instead of "Regards" or vice-versa.

Comment: This question asks what is the difference between x, y, z... where as the [linked "duplicate" question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/332/which-expressions-can-be-used-to-close-an-email) asks for "give me a list of 'insert subject A' and a list of 'insert subject B'".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm from the UK and I personally use 'Regards' on its own, like you.  Even to somebody I don't know.  That's usually for the initial contact type of email, when I'm first raising a subject with somebody.  Subsequent responses tend to become less formal, with either a simple 'Thanks' or no ending at all.

However, from your list above, I most often see 'Kind Regards' and in fact I received an email with this today.  I'd suggest you could rank those in order of formality: Sincerely > Best Regards > Kind Regards.

I've pretty much never seen 'Sincerely' in an email though, as I think the medium is intrinsically less formal than other methods.  In my opinion, there are ways to increase the formality slightly, such as by avoiding contractions for example.